# HTML create form entries dynamically?

Tags: php, json, facebook, html

I have a `JSON` file containing Facebook data from pages. What I need is to create a `table` with `checkbox` entries based on the `JSON` file. I am using **php sdk** and **javascript sdk**.

I'm thinking of a kind of method like this:

```
<?php
$array_of_decoded=json_decode("$myjson",true);
for($i=0;$array_of_decoded(i);i++)
{?>
// create new entry in html form with the following propreties:
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php array_of_decoded(i)['name']?>"
 value="<?php array_of_decoded(i)['id']?>"><?php array_of_decoded(i)['name']?<br>
<?php
//...
}?>
```

My JSON files has entries like the following:

```
{"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Yann Tiersen (official)","id":"18359161762"}
```

I am a newbie in this, and the code above might be wrong, I just wrote it on the spot, didn't test it. Does anyone have an idea how can I create the new entry? And does the code above show how to decode the json properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it using "`foreach`":

```
<?php
foreach(json_decode("$myjson",true) as $element) {?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $element['name']?>" value="<?php echo $element['id']?>"><?php echo $element['name']?><br>
<?php }?>
```

Of course, this must be placed in the view page!

Comment: thanks, just started implementing it